# Nexus 2.10 broken pipe IOException

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, nexus

I am using nexus 2.10 having recently upgraded from nexus 2.8. The reason I upgraded was because I was getting the following exception in my logs and thus the jar was not downloaded and Nexus 2.10 gives a few more details in the log regarding the broken pipe error.

So in my logs I get the following error (replaced i[p address with string host name).

```
2014-10-21 15:18:22,556+0100 INFO  [qtp-855494215-66] anonymous org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.storage.remote.httpclient.HttpClientRemoteStorage - Initializing remote transport for proxy repository "Central" [id=central]...
2014-10-21 15:23:59,440+0100 WARN  [qtp-855494215-69] anonymous org.sonatype.nexus.content.internal.ContentServlet - org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException, caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe [client=host.name,ua=m2e/3.9.1.v20130814-1242/1.4.0.20130601-0317/1.6.0_45,req=GET http://xx.xx:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.1.1.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar]
2014-10-21 15:24:43,329+0100 WARN  [qtp-855494215-67] anonymous org.sonatype.nexus.content.internal.ContentServlet - org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException, caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe [client=host.name,ua=m2e/3.9.1.v20130814-1242/1.4.0.20130601-0317/1.6.0_45,req=GET http://xx.xx5:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.1.1.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar]
2014-10-21 15:24:58,333+0100 WARN  [qtp-855494215-66] anonymous org.sonatype.nexus.content.internal.ContentServlet - org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException, caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe [client=host.name,ua=m2e/3.9.1.v20130814-1242/1.4.0.20130601-0317/1.6.0_45,req=GET http://xx.xx:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/springframework/spring-context/4.1.1.RELEASE/spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources.jar]
```

Can anyone advise how to get past this error because currently some jars are not being downloaded. This does not apply to all jars for eg i just downloaded the nekohtml-0.9.5.jar no issues. Could this be possibly something to do with size? In my maven repository I just get a spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar.lastUpdated jar which is only 1kb in size.

Also I am running behind a firewall so have a proxy server configured in the nexus settings.

UPDATE:

this seems to be an issue only when done through eclipse. I was able to download sources and jars etc fine when I did it from the command line. I am using Eclipse keplar and the m2e plugin. Can anyone comment on this?

All advice appreciated
Thanks

Comment: An easy way to talk to their developers directly is via their HipChat channel: https://links.sonatype.com/products/nexus/community-chat. I'm sure they'll be interested, if this is a bug. They're usually quite helpful.

Answer (score 4):

The broken pipe exception occurs when nexus has received an http request from a client, prepares a response, but when it goes to write the response it finds the socket has already been closed.

Likely causes of this are:

1. An end user initiating a request and then canceling it (or
   navigating away from a web page before it completes)
2. A client which does not properly close socket connections
3. A client's read timeout setting being reached
4. A reverse proxy in between nexus and the client (such as apache or
   nginx) terminating the connection

Therefore you'll need to begin your investigation on the client side.  If it turns out the client or reverse proxy's read timeout setting is triggering this then you'll need to investigate why nexus is responding slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Your Nexus server is probably not able to reach some external repositories if it is running inside a network behind a proxy. You have to make sure you have the http proxy configured in Nexus and that any URL's of remote proxy repositories you want to access are allowed in the proxy.

You can use the "Browse Remote" feature to check if the access works. More details are in the Nexus book http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/configxn-sect-customizing-server.html

Comment: This issue happens for me when downloading from central. And if it was a http proxy configuration then would that not impact all downloads from that respository? In my case i can download some jars from central and not others. Also I dont see any issue browsing the remote or actually downloading the jar from the nexus UI